# How do I use JavaScript (not jQuery) to make something display:none?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an element called `"#container-main"`. How do I make that `display:none` NOT using jQuery?

Comment: ! ($('#container-main').css('display', 'none'));

;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('container-main').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: And you need to do this after the element is rendered. Either by placing your script after the element, or using a `window.onload` handler.

Comment: Should be `getElementById` (note case).

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming that you mean the `id` attribute of the container is `container-main`. Then in JavaScript you do

```
document.getElementById('container-main').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the other answers are correct, for the sake of preventing a potential error, I would recommend getting a reference to your DOM element first, then making sure it exists and has properties, rather than encapsulating everything in a one liner.  If, for some reason, the element with id 'container-main' no longer existed on the page, the suggested one-liner will create a JS error.

```
var myNode = document.getElementById('container-main'); // Attempt to get the reference first
if ( myNode && myNode.style ) { // make sure you did get an element, and if so...
    myNode.style.display = 'none'; // then operate on it's properties.
}
```

Additionally, many people have the erroneous notion that each successive property alteration on the node requires another call to getElementById... this is not the case, and requires additional DOM traversal (which can become slow).

```
document.getElementById('container-main').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('container-main').style.color = 'black'; // getting by id a second time can be slow
```

-

```
var myNode = document.getElementById('container-main');
if ( myNode && myNode.style ) {
    myNode.style.display = 'none';
    myNode.style.color = 'black'; // but using a reference a second time costs nothing.
}
```

Comment: Agreed, this was the comment I was going to make. Check that the element was retrieved successfully before trying to set the style property.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('container-main').style.display = 'none';
```

`display='none'` hides the element so it doesn't take up any space, whereas `display='hidden'` still takes up space but is just not viewable.

Answer (score 0):

edited:
`document.getElementById('container-main').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Is there really a `display` field on the DOM object itself? The answers above seem to agree that `display` is part of the `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
document.getElementById('container-main').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: You could, but that would not set `display: none`, and the effect really is quite different.

Comment: @Jorn: my bad. but what would be the difference between the two approaches?